# Change single icon size in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

Is it possible to change size of the icon in the Navigation Drawer?
I know that it is possible to set size for all of the icons:

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size"tools:override="true">40dp</dimen>
```

But is it possible to change size only of one of the icon in Navigation Drawer?